# Ubuntu system error during "apt install" seems to have left a mess

Tags: apt, package-management

Edit:  The answer was to delete libjpeg9-dev using "dpkg -r" directly rather than depending on the apt command.  Removing libjpeg9-dev and then running "apt --fix-broken install" cleared the problem.

During "apt install libtiff-dev" I got an "Ubuntu internal error" message.  Coincidence or not, related or not, I have a problem with "apt install" since rebooting.  I tried to do "apt install whois" and got

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff-dev : Depends: libjpeg-dev
```

along with a suggestion to run "apt --fix-broken install".  Doing that offers to install "libjpeg-turbo8-dev"; accepting that suggestion wins

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/jerror.h', which is also in package  libjpeg9-dev:amd64 1:9d-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

libjpeg9-dev is in fact installed, but libjpeg-dev, which libtiff-dev is really complaining about, is not installed.  Attempting to install it tells me that it depends on libjpeg8-dev, but says it is not going to install that.

Attempting to install it myself gets me:

```
libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8-dev (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6)
but it is not going to be installed
libjpeg9-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg8-dev but 8c-2ubuntu8 is to be installed
```

So I'm kind of stuck here.

The long and short of it seems to be that libtiff5 depends on libjpeg8 but I have libjpeg9 installed and that creates a conflict.  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to dig out of this hole.

Thanks for any help.

Full output from my attempt to remove libjpeg9-dev in the process of fixing the installation of libtiff, which has an unmet dependency of libjpeg-dev:

```
# apt remove libjpeg9-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff-dev : Depends: libjpeg-dev
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
# 
# 
# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/238 kB of archives.
After this operation, 988 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 249664 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-turbo8-dev_2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64 (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_2.0.3-
0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/jerror.h', which is also in package libjpeg9-
dev:amd64 1:9d-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Correct: `libjpeg9-dev` and `libjpeg8-dev` conflict. They cannot be simultaneously installed. Since nothing in Ubuntu depends upon `libjpeg9-dev`, one simple solution is to uninstall that package, perhaps temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, apt won't let me remove libjpeg9-dev because it gives me an "unmet dependencies" error (from libtiff for libjpeg-dev) and quits.  --fix-broken wants to install libjpeg-turbo8-dev, but that fails because libjpeg9-dev remains installed despite my best efforts.

Comment: Add the complete output to your question. Summaries are confusing and lack important context.

Comment: I've appended the full output to the end of my original report.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove --force libjpeg9-dev`. Use --force with caution: It may cause tremendous damage if used unwisely.

Comment: "apt remove --force libjpeg9-dev" wins "Command line option --force is not understood in combination with the other options"

Comment: Perhaps I should try "--force-depends"?

Comment: @user535733 I neglected to tag you in my response to your comment; sorry.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on `sudo apt install r-base`. This has a dependency on libjpeg-turbo8-dev but the installed libjpeg9-dev caused a conflict. The following fixed it for me

```
sudo dpkg -r libjpeg9-dev
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I should have tumbled to the idea of using dpkg directly instead of depending entirely on apt ... I appreciate your help